# Does Tor add encryption at the TCP protocol level?

Tags: socks, protocol

Just wondering if http://www.tcpcrypt.org/ would be useful to add?
Also is there any work being done to replace/add encryption at the ODI level?

Comment: OSI Doh apparently I can't type non spell check :) Not being able to edit OP is bad, should have timer of 30 seconds or so.

Comment: This is not a forum.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't a good idea.

1. TCPCrypt is, and I can't stress this enough, *absolute trash*.

   - It provides *no protection* against an active MITM attacker, it's not authenticated.
2. The remote party too must support TCPCrypt, otherwise it won't work.

   - Any remote party could just use TLS or an onion service and gain *greater* protection than that offered by TCPCrypt.

Tor *cannot* magically add crypto to traffic after leaves the network, it *absolutely **must*** be the responsibility of applications sending data over Tor to apply appropriate levels of cryptography to their communications, there is no alternative.

Comment: "It provides no protection against an active MITM attacker, it's not authenticated."   Idon't understand this, what does provide protection from an ACTIVE MITM??? Nothing that I know of. Doesn't this encrypt traffic after the connection is made? So if you already have a MITM your screwed anyway. But it should help from picking up a MITM after your connected right?

Comment: "nothing that I know of" only speaks to the limits of your knowledge :)

Comment: I am Joe's utter disregard for your opinions. I gave two examples in my answer of systems that resist active MITM attackers. TCPCrypt does not verify the remote party is who they say they are, it performs an unauthenticated key exchange.

Comment: I'm bored by this now. Try harder.

Comment: I also am bored by your transparent attempts at weakening the average users ability to protect themselves, I have read your misconceptions and see errors that sound logical to a n00b but will inversely effect their privacy. So go away and soft troll another topic.

Comment: You have no idea what you're talking about. Also ur mom.

Comment: Heuristic, this is not a forum. Why don't you go find an IRC channel to vent your misunderstanding. When you're done with that, Google how a MITM attack actually works. Also Google how StackExchange works. It's a professional question and answer site, not a forum to argue in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

No it does not. Tor makes your "request->destination" chain to be private, at the exit node traffic is released "as-is", no modifications

Comment: Thanks for the reply, would it be a bad idea for this to be bundled? It seems to me this should be spread yet today is the first time I've ever seen it.

Comment: @Hueristic it's a good idea, I'm currently workingo on a similar one for Tor, but for ability to physically set keys+algos+etc for node-to-node communications